# dragging object along and within path only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag

I'm having a terrible time trying to code in Flash for a small game level.

I'm trying to drag an object within a path using a mouse pointer. And whenever the object hits the path boundary it shouldn't go beyond. Can anyone help me. I'm a noob in flash actionscript 3. 
Any help would be much much appreciated !Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more a mathe problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're looking for is termed "Bitmap Hit Testing."  It goes beyond the level of  the regular hit test checking.

In regular hit testing (like `obj.hitTestObject(otherobj)`), Flash is checking the "boundary boxes" against each other.  For instance, if you have two green circles you're trying to hit test against each other, they will register as colliding even if the **corners which appear white are touching.**  There's an invisible bound box surrounding the circle that's colliding with the other invisible bound box surrounding the other circle.

Bitmap hit testing, on the other hand, is significantly slower and complex, but much more accurate.  It is actually checking pixel per pixel whether the two images are colliding.  In this case then, bitmaps can be irregular shapes with say, a path within, like this:

[image: Please excuse my terrible Paint skills; the Bitmap is yellow and the empty space is red.]

I would recommend looking at http://www.freeactionscript.com/tag/using-bitmapdata-hittest/ for a demo to make sure that this is what you're looking for, and then http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/ for an explanation, both by Mike Chambers.

I surmise that your process would be a conversion of both of your clips (the dragged object and the "walls" of the path) into BitmapData (do some quick research), and then a simple method call of the BitmapData.hitTest for your checking.  Let me know if you have any questions or need any additional clarification :-)